# JUnit test - method called on class instance

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I have a problem with JUnit test for my method

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void deleteOffer(Offer offer) {
    List<String> offerPictures = this.getOfferPictures(offer);
    if (offerPictures != null) {
        System.out.println(offerPictures.size());
        for (String stringName : offerPictures) {
            this.deleteSinglePhoto(new File(hardDiscAddress + stringName));
            this.deleteSinglePhoto(new File(hardDiscAddress + "sm_" + stringName));
        }
    }
    offerDAO.delete(offer.getId());
}
```

I already have test for empty `offerPcitures` list, but now I need to write one for **NOT empty** list. Problem is I don't know how to mock `getOfferPictures` method to return not empty string list

```
@Override
public List<String> getOfferPictures(Offer offer) {
    File dir = new File(hardDiscAddress);
    List<String> resultantlist = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (dir.isDirectory()) {
        for (final File f : dir.listFiles()) {
            if (f.getName().startsWith(offer.getPhotography())) {
                resultantlist.add(f.getName());
            }
        }
    }
    return resultantlist;
}
```

And this is the test for **empty** list

```
@Test
public void testDeleteOffer() {
    // given
    testOfferServiceImpl = new OfferServiceImpl();
    testOfferServiceImpl.hardDiscAddress = "C:/";
    testOfferServiceImpl.offerDAO = offerDAOMock;
    when(offerMock.getId()).thenReturn(1);
    when(offerMock.getPhotography()).thenReturn("stringForTest");
    doNothing().when(offerDAOMock).delete(1);
    // when
    testOfferServiceImpl.deleteOffer(offerMock);
    // then
    Mockito.verify(offerDAOMock, times(1)).delete(1);
}
```

Comment: Partial mock the class you're testing and then expect the call to `getOfferPictures(Offer offer)` to return the list you're after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Mockito.spy` to partially mock the instance you're testing, and return a non empty list:

```
@Test
public void testNotEmptyOffer() {
    // Given
    testOfferServiceImpl = new OfferServiceImpl();
    testOfferServiceImpl.hardDiscAddress = "C:/";
    testOfferServiceImpl.offerDAO = offerDAOMock;

    // Spy (partially mock) the object
    testOfferServiceImpl = Mockito.spy(testOfferServiceImpl);
    doReturn(Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three")).
       when(testOfferServiceImpl).getOfferPictures(offerMock)

    // Test your logic here
}
```

Comment: thanks! that solved my problem. partial mock was what I needed :)

Answer (score 0):

Use something like Mockito. You can do:

```
Candidate candidate = mock(Candidate.class);
when(candidate.getFirstName()).thenReturn("Bob");
```

this is an example from project, works well. You will also have to annotate your test class with:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
```

you can then make the method return whatever you like. Hope that helps :)